# Learning SQL - Selecting details from same table based off ItemID

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am in the process of learning SQL. I have a table that has the details of all orders placed.  I need to locate all order that contain a specific item. SO i need to select the ItemID = 102011 to get the order numbers and them select all of the records by OrderId that have that item. I am not sure exactly how to make this happen.

Everything is in one table.

Thanks

Comment: Please add the table definitions. This would help with answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (assuming a certain amount of your table structure):

```
select *
from yourOrdersTable
where ItemID = 102011
order by OrderId
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by everything is in one table. Can you post the table structures?
In an offshot that this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT * FROM <orders_table> 
WHERE order_id IN (SELECT * FROM <orders_table> WHERE ItemID = 102011)
```

or this

```
SELECT * FROM <orders_table> WHERE ItemID = 102011 ORDER BY OrderId
```

Answer (score 0):

This will likely depend on your flavour of SQL, but in SQL Server something like the following will work fine:

```
SELECT * FROM OrdersItems WHERE OrderID IN (SELECT OrderID FROM OrderItems WHERE ItemId = 102011)
```